# How to await all files to be read and all callbacks executed before continue

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, asynchronous

I'm using node.js and trying to read 3 xlsx files at the same time and only when all the 3 files whas readen and the callback executed, return all of them in a array.

I try to use Promise.all but I'm getting the array before the callbacks are done.

Here is the code

```
const path = require('path');
const extractor = require("xlsx-to-json");

(async () =>{
  let x = [];

  const dir = 'my/path';

  const files = [
      { name:'File1.xlsx'},
      { name:'File2.xlsx' },
      { name:'File3.xlsx'}
  ];

  await Promise.all(
          files.map(async (file)=>{   
          console.log('init: %s',file.name);
          let start = new Date();

          let filePath = path.resolve(dir,file.name);

          extractor({
              input: filePath,
              output: null
          }, function(err, result) {
              if(err) {
                  console.error(err);
              } else {
                  x.push(result);
                  let end = new Date() - start;
                  console.info('Extraction time of [%s]: %dms', file.name, end);
              }
          });
      })
  );  
  console.log(x);    
})();
```

The output I need is:

```
init: File1.xlsx
init: File2.xlsx
init: File3.xlsx
Extraction time of [File1.xlsx]: 17233ms
Extraction time of [File2.xlsx]: 16615ms
Extraction time of [File3.xlsx]: 15266ms
[ some json objects ]
```

But I get the following:

```
init: File1.xlsx
init: File2.xlsx
init: File3.xlsx
[] //empty array
Extraction time of [File1.xlsx]: 17233ms
Extraction time of [File2.xlsx]: 16615ms
Extraction time of [File3.xlsx]: 15266ms
```

Comment: Don't mix plain callbacks and promises.  Your `extractor()` function is not even remotely related to the promise that is returned from `files.map()`, therefore the `await` is not connected to it either.  Wrap `extractor()` in a promise interface and return that promise from your `.map()` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the `util.promisify()` version of what I suggested earlier in the comment:

```
const path = require('path');
const extractor = require("xlsx-to-json");
const util = require('util');
const extractorP = util.promisify(extractor);

const dir = 'my/path';

const files = [
      { name:'File1.xlsx'},
      { name:'File2.xlsx' },
      { name:'File3.xlsx'}
];

Promise.all(
    files.map((file) => {   
        console.log('init: %s',file.name);
        let start = new Date();

        let filePath = path.resolve(dir,file.name);

        // return promise from files.map() callback so we get
        // an array of promises    
        return extractorP({
            input: filePath,
            output: null
        }).then(result => {
            let end = new Date() - start;
            console.info('Extraction time of [%s]: %dms', file.name, end);
            return result;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            throw err;
        });
    });
).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    // put error handling here
});
```

I think it's always cleaner to promisify outside the implementation and then have an implementation that only uses promises.  The whole logic flow just seems cleaner if there's no mix of promises and regular callbacks and, of course, if you use this function anywhere else, you can use the promisified version elsewhere too.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Promise.all` was on the righ track, but you didn't use it correctly.

Please see inline comment below

```
const path = require('path');
const extractor = require("xlsx-to-json");

(async () => {
    //let x = [];

    const dir = 'my/path';

    const files = [
        { name: 'File1.xlsx' },
        { name: 'File2.xlsx' },
        { name: 'File3.xlsx' }
    ];

    // all 3 extracted results will be returned from `await Promise.all()`
    let x = await Promise.all(

        // `async` not needed here
        files.map(/*async*/ (file) => {
            console.log('init: %s', file.name);
            let start = new Date();

            let filePath = path.resolve(dir, file.name);

            // Promise wrapper
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                extractor({
                    input: filePath,
                    output: null
                }, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);

                        // return error by rejecting the Promise
                        reject(err);      

                    } else {
                        // x.push(result);

                        // return result by resolving the Promise
                        resolve(result);  

                        let end = new Date() - start;
                        console.info('Extraction time of [%s]: %dms', file.name, end);
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    );

    console.log(x);
})();
```

Comment: Thaks, this helped a lot. I came to something close to this after researching the alteration sugested by @jfriend00. But your solution should help someone else to understanding too :)

I guess is there a way to do the same using the Node’s “util” module, right? By using "util.promisify()"